# Hover off delay on jquery script

Tags: jquery, hover, timedelay

I am using this script to enable a dropdown menu and want to be able to allow a hover off delay for a second or two. Can anyone assist me with this?

```
        ( function( $ ) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#cssmenu').prepend('<div id="menu-button">Menu</div>');
      $('#cssmenu #menu-button').on('click', function(){
        var menu = $(this).next('ul');
        if (menu.hasClass('open')) {
          menu.removeClass('open');
        }
        else {
          menu.addClass('open');
        }
      });
    });
    } )( jQuery );
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not seeing any code for hovering in nor out, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

The event for hover off is `mouseout`, you can attach an event handler, and set a timeout, something like this:

```
$('ul').on('mouseout', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    }, 1000);
});
```